# Check All shard of index has been deleted from Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have deleted the index from the elastic search with **DELETE API**. But during my deletion, some of the shards may not be connected to clusters due to some node failure or network issue. So after deletion the index I have to check that all shard has been deleted properly so that I can take action accordingly (Including execute DELETE API again) so for the check that all shard has been deleted can I use **GET /_cat/indices/indexname** to check. The issue of checking is that some node holing a shard may not be connected to cluster at the time of checking. And I want to know that some shard still there in somewhere (In which node?, I am not interested in)

**GET /_cat/indices/indexname** returns

- Shard count
- Document count
- Deleted document count
- Primary store size
- Total store size of all shards, including shard replica

Comment: I think the correct question to ask yourself first is why some nodes might not be connected to your cluster, that's not a normal situation.

Comment: multiple reasons, sometimes we manually disconnect node for some time for maintenance. during that time if delete job runs it will not delete unassign shard. this partially deleted shard creating the problem.

Comment: If you plan on taking down a node for a long maintenance, you should [move all shards away from that node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#cluster-shard-allocation-filtering) first and then perform your maintenance. An alternative would be to pause your delete jobs during the maintenance.